# How to get the average of time interval between DateTime values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So I have a **DateTime** column. What I need is to get the average number of intervals (by seconds) per person. So my dataframe currently looks like this:

| No | AccountID | Agent | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ##### | Agent A | 10/19/2021 15:00 |
| 1 | ##### | Agent B | 10/19/2021 14:13 |
| 2 | ##### | Agent C | 10/19/2021 15:24 |
| 3 | ##### | Agent D | 10/19/2021 10:54 |
| 4 | ##### | Agent E | 10/19/2021 10:51 |

Now what I wanted to do is.

1. create another column to have the interval between the current date/time vs prev date/time. Which Would look something like this:

   | No | AccountID | Agent | DateTime | Intervals in Seconds |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 0 | ##### | Agent A | 10/19/2021 15:00 | ? |
   | 1 | ##### | Agent B | 10/19/2021 14:13 | ? |
   | 2 | ##### | Agent C | 10/19/2021 15:24 | ? |
   | 3 | ##### | Agent D | 10/19/2021 10:54 | ? |
   | 4 | ##### | Agent E | 10/19/2021 10:51 | ? |
2. Be able to see the average interval per **Agent** on a monthly basis.

I did my research but I got nowhere. I don't need the entire solution…just some advice on where I can start.

Comment: What does that _the interval between the current date/time vs prev date/time_ mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and `diff` to calculate the differences. You need to sort the rows first. And to get the result in seconds use `Series.astype`:

```
df.sort_values(['Agent', 'DateTime'], inplace=True)
df['interval'] = df.groupby('Agent').DateTime.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]')
```